# What's the current status of JS/ES proposals on date literals?

Tags: javascript, literals

The page [proposals:date_literal_syntax](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals%3adate_literal_syntax) at ecmascipt wiki says:

> Spec retracted 2006-08-28 following meeting on 2006-08-23; proposals for supporting a sensible date syntax have been folded into [proposals:date_and_time](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals%3adate_and_time).

However, that page does not even mention date literals at all.

As date literals would be very useful for some JSON vNext syntax (e.g. [JSON5](http://json5.org/)), I am interested on what's their current state, and why they were retracted.

Comment: "It remains a *strict subset* of JavaScript, adds no new data types.." - but JavaScript has no literals for Dates/Times.

Comment: Having coded JS since 1995, I fail to see the need for JSON5 or date literals as long as you pay attention to what you do. To suggest that arrays or objects should be allowed to have trailing commas irritates me no end. I can specify any date I need so far.

Comment: @mplungjan I agree with the general sentiments. If JSON is to be "updated", there are more interesting things than to make it more JS-like.

Comment: PS: dateString
String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601). - this works in most newer browsers if not all: "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 06:33:56 +0200"

Comment: I fail to see how date literals in ES have anything to do with JSON5. *edit:* OK, it wants to stay a subset of ES, but that's the projects problem IMO.

Comment: @mplungjan _Having coded JS since 1995, I fail to see the need for JSON5 or date literals as long as you pay attention to what you do._ How is attention relevant here? JSON is mostly used as a data transfer and configuration format. It is pretty strict at what it allows, so currently there is no way to specify date at all, without defining some additional protocol for that.

Comment: @FelixKling well it would be weird to be a 95% subset of JS, _except_ for one special case around dates.

Comment: One can argue that JSON is already not a true subset : http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset. And I'm not sure I would mind if JSON diverged more from ES. At least people wouldn't confuse object literals with JSON anymore :-/

Comment: @FelixKling that's very interesting -- though looks more like a bug in JSON spec that got propagated to parser implementations than a conscious decision.

Comment: @FelixKling why is this opinion-based btw? the question is not about usefulness of the feature, but rather about its status in the standards process, which should be unambiguous for a given moment of time.

Comment: I guess the part with "date literals would be useful..." put me off a little, and in general your question seems to be more the start of a discussion. I think you will for a better response on the es discuss mailing list (because that's where the people working on the spec are).

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I'll consider different phrasing next time. it's ok as nobody seems to know the answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the proposal, I would say "Date/Time Literals are Dead". The article(s) referenced were last updated in 2008 (6+ years) while neither [ES5](http://es5.github.io/) nor [ES6-draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html) support such literals per the grammar rules.

Since there is no Date/Time literal in ES5, such cannot be represented in [JSON5](http://json5.org/) as literals because it has a goal of being a "strict subset of JavaScript". JSON5 looks to expand JSON to encompass more JavaScript literal syntax<sup>1</sup> constructs, but does not cover non-literal forms like `new Date("ISO8601")`.

---

<sup>1</sup> [JSON](http://www.json.org/) is *not* JavaScript, despite sharing a word in the name; just a [mostly-compatible](http://timelessrepo.com/json-isnt-a-javascript-subset) serialization format. (Which is why JSON5 makes me go *ugh!* it complicates the format/processing while the biggest compatiblity target - JavaScript ed.5 - does not sanely rely on "eval" to handle JSON.)